# BLDC Current Driver Encountering Current Problems

Tags: mosfet, motor, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, mosfet-driver

The attached Schematic uses 6 **N Channel Power Mosfets "IRL3303"**. I have wound my inrunner bldc motor with **180** windings per phase using a **26 Gauge Magnetic Wire**. My motor is a 6 pole 2 magnets machine. The encountered problem is defined below.

[image: 3 Phase Current Driver Schematic]

**Q. The mosfet being used has a Vgs Threshold as 1V. Arduino outputs are being used to power the mosfets(state-machine). Even at 15V VCC the drawn current by the motor is around *0.6AMPS*. I have checked the winding connections seperately and it draws 2Amps at around 3-4V. My resistance per phase is around 5ohm and inductance 1.5mH. I have no clue how to fix it. Your input would be really appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: "Even at 15V VCC the drawn current by the motor is around 0.6AMPS. I have checked the winding connections seperately and it draws 2Amps at around 3-4V", now what?? Does it draw 0.6A at 15V or 2A at 4V? You didn't mention the speed of motor, and if your state machine follows the rotor position - do you have any feedback like hall sensor or back EMF to give you the switch position?

Comment: What do your high side drivers look like? You can't just connect the upper FETs to Arduino pins.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely not driving the high-side MOSFET with enough voltage to turn it on. You need to have VCC+1V or more at the gate to turn those on fully. Typically you would use a gate-driver IC to do this, which has a built-in boost circuit (bootstrap circuit).